# Potato chips lose crunch and taste within a week

Tags: baking, food-safety, food-science, food-preservation

We make potato chips commercially, but they lose crunch and taste within 7 days.

How can one delay or prevent potato chips from losing their crunchiness and taste?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/93937/potato-chips-lose-crunch-and-taste-within-7-days?rq=1

Comment: Khuram, welcome! Please don’t post your question twice - if you want to increase the probability of getting an answer, *improve the question*: Many users have posted comments asking about your procedure and other clarifications. You may also want to read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

How do you store/package them ?

AFAIK, commercial chips are stored in bags filled with nitrogen to prevent oxydation.

https://indianapublicmedia.org/amomentofscience/potato-chips-stay-fresh-bag/